# How to show this map between Zariski tangent spaces is injective

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

Let $f: X \rightarrow Y$ be a flat morphism of finite type of schemes and let $Z$ be a closed subscheme of $Y$. I want to consider $X \times_{Y} Z$. Let $x \in X \times_Y Z$ such that $f(x) \in Z$. Let $\pi: X \times_Y Z \rightarrow X$. 
This induces a map between the tangent spaces
$$
T_x X \times_Y Z \rightarrow T_{\pi(x)}X \otimes_{k(\pi(x))}k(x).  
$$
$k(x)$ is the residue field of $x$. 
I was wondering how can I deduce that this map is injective? Any comments would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Try to use the fact that closed immersions are stable under base change. In particular, as $Z \rightarrow Y$ is a closed immersion, then so is $X \times_Y Z \rightarrow X$.

Comment: For simplicity: $X\times_YZ=f^{-1}(Z)$...